# error in running qwt program

Tags: c++, linux, qwt

hi every one i have installed qwt and include the path

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qwt-6.0.0-rc5/include

LIBS += -L/usr/local/qwt-6.0.0-rc5/lib -lqwt

in my pro file

but when i run my program i get the error

error while loading shared libraries: libqwt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/cv/abc/abc exited with code 127

even i remove the paths i.e INCLUDE and LIBS and all qwt related thing i am still getting an error am i missing some thing kingly help me

i am using ubuntu 10.04
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375523/how-to-set-qwt-path-or-environment-variable

Answer (score 3):

In order to execute any program using a shared library, you have to specify where they are.

In your case, you are using shared libraries located at /usr/local/gwt-6.0.0-rc5/lib and you have to tell Linux "ld" that this path is a library path.

To do that, you can include this path at the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable or add it to the /etc/ld.so.conf (or even as a file inside /etc/ld.so.conf.d). After that, ensure you run "ldconfig" make the system aware of this change and try again.

Comment: thank u sir but tell me where to write LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable and how ?and how to run idconfig thanks and i am sorry if my question sound silly as i have no idea of ubuntu and qwt