# how to set qwt path or environment variable

Tags: c++, linux, qwt

I have installed qwt and include the path

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qwt-6.0.0-rc5/include

LIBS += -L/usr/local/qwt-6.0.0-rc5/lib -lqwt
```

in my profile.

But when I run my program i get the error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libqwt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory /home/cv/abc/abc exited with code 127
```

When using terminal I set the path

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/qwt-6.0.0-rc5
```

Then when I run the program (using the play button of the interface) I am still getting an error. I don't know where I'm wrong, I'm totally stuck. Can someone explain me in detail  how to make qwt work with qt? Does version make any difference? Please explain me in detail I shall be very thank full!

I am using ubuntu 10.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You can install qwt in ubuntu way

   aptitude install libqwt-dev
2. Also in qtreator you can specify Run Enviroment for your project. Select Projects in left panel and goto Run Setting.

Comment: thanks  u sir is there a way to permanatly set this like i want to open qt creator from application->programming thanks

Comment: Try put `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path>` in .gnomerc, you can edit /etc/ld.so.conf also, but that will affect all system.

Comment: thank u sir please tell me where.gnomerc and where should i paste the ld_library_path ........in that file

Comment: `echo export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path> >> ~/.gnomerc`.

Comment: thanks so much for your help but sir i have run the above command but i am till getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the path to Qwt to the run-time linker?

In `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` create a file `qwt.conf` where you just write the path to `[your-qwt-path]/lib`.

EDIT: You will, of course, need root privileges to create a file there. Also, I forgot to mention you will need to `sudo ldconfig` after creating that file. Lastly, it didn't work until I rebooted my system. :)